# How to use javascript onclick on a DIV tag to toggle visibility of a section that contains clickable links?

Tags: javascript, css, prototypejs, scriptaculous

Hi I've got a DIV section that has only its title visible initially. What I would like to achieve is that when the visitor clicks anywhere on the area of `toggle_section` the `toggle_stuff` div toggles between visible/hidden.

```
<div id="toggle_section" 
     onclick="javascript: new Effect.toggle('toggle_stuff', 'slide');">
    <div id="toggle_title">Some title</div>
    <div id="toggle_stuff">
        some content stuff
        <a href="/foo.php">Some link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the way it is set-up right now, if I have any `<a>` link within the `toggle_section`, clicking that link will also execute the onclick event.

Then my question is what would be the best way to set this type of behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most simple solution is to **add an extra onclick handler to the link** within your DIV which stops event propagation:

```
<div id="toggle_section" 
     onclick="javascript: new Effect.toggle('toggle_stuff', 'slide');">
    <div id="toggle_title">Some title</div>
    <div id="toggle_stuff">
        some content stuff
        <a href="/foo.php"
            onclick="Event.stop(event);"
        >Some link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above example uses Prototype's [`Event.stop()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/event/stop) function in order to facilitate a cross browser event propagation stop.

As you use the inline `onclick()` handler, most (if not all) browser will traverse the event in the bubbling phase first (which is what you want).

A good guide to understanding the actual reasons behind this behaviour and the differences between *event capturing* and *event bubbling* can be found at the excellent [Quirksmode.](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

Answer (score 4):

in script :

```
function overlayvis(blck) {
  el = document.getElementById(blck.id);
  el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
}
```

activator link, followed by content (no reason that couldn't be else on the page):

```
<div onclick='overlayvis(showhideme)">show/hide stuff</div>
<div id="showhideme">
  ... content to hide / unhide ...
</div>
```

I got this from [Modal window javascript css overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578427/modal-window-javascript-css-overlay) - had to search for the source and was pleased to find it was this site. :)

Answer (score 2):

After I posted my first question I could not wait to try to think about it once more and it seems that I have found a quite simple way to achieve this.

I have moved the onlick `Effect.toggle` into a separate function like:

```
function someClick(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName == 'A') {
        return;
    } else {
        new Effect.toggle('toggle_stuff', 'slide');
    }
}
```

I suppose this would only work for `A` tags and not anything else that is clickable though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this would work, but try giving the link element a bigger `z-index` value than the toggle_section div.

something like :

```
#toggle_section a { z-index: 10; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick handler to stop event propagation.

With JQuery use:
onclick="event.stopPropagation()"

With Prototype use:
onclick="Event.stop(event)"